# How to give each JButton in a 10 x 10 grid button layout a unique ID/name

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to give each JButton from a 10 x 10 button layout (so 100 buttons) each unique name or ID or number so I can call them later. I made an ArrayList because that's what some other person did.

```
public ArrayList<JButton> myList;

//Some other code

        for(int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col < 10; col++)
            {
                    button = new JButton();
                    button.addActionListener( al );
                    myList.add(button);
                    for(JButton button : myList)
                        button.setText("");
                    panel_1.add(button);
            }
        }
```

The program compiles but it doesn't run. It's showing error at

```
myList.add(button);
```

It's a null pointer exception apparently.

but I don't know why. Is it not adding the buttons to the ArrayList? Also how do I give each button a unique name or string?

Comment: `It's showing error at` - we are not (always) mind readers. Tell us the error when you ask a question. Don't expect us to guess.

Comment: @camickr it's showing a null pointer exception. I assume it's because no ArrayList has been made.

Comment: (1-) `I assume it's because no ArrayList has been made.` - so if you know what the problem is why did you ask a question??? Fix the problem!!!

Comment: @camickr I wasn't sure damn, I don't know if it's been created or not. Anyways I only found out that after I found that it was a null pointer exception.

Comment: `JButton@#setActionCommand`?

Comment: `I only found out that after I found that it was a null pointer exception` - that is my point. You stated in the question you had a NPE. So don't assume what the problem is and ask a question. Instead try solving the problem based one your assumption. In other words to some basic problem solving first before posting a question. In any case you have already been given an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> The program compiles but it doesn't run. It's showing error at

The ArrayList is null because you didn't create an ArrayList object.

The code should be:

```
private ArrayList<JButton> myList = new ArrayList<JButton>();
```

> Also how do I give each button a unique name or string?

There is no need to give the button a unique name. Its unique name is the "index" used to access the `JButton` in the `ArrayList`.

You probably don't even need the ArrayList.

Normally you add an `ActionListener` to the button. Then you can just use the `getSource()` method of the `ActionEvent` to get the reference to the button.

Comment: However, you can give each button a name if you want to, using button.setName(). For example, the name could be "Row=3 Column=5". Note that this is different from the text displayed in the button, set by button.setText().

Comment: @FredK, this has nothing to do with my suggestion. Please remove the comment. If you think this is the solution then add your own answer or add a comment to the question.